# Запрос на использование данных

Tags: android

Пришло письмо счастья, и вот решил сделать политику конфидециальности, но еще оказывается в правилах в отношении данных пользователей написано **"В политике конфиденциальности и запросе на использование данных нужно подробно объяснить, какие данные собираются и передаются, как они используются и кто может получить к ним доступ."**  как мне объяснять в **запросе на использование** есть готовый api для того чтобы я мог описать что я хочу делать с этими данными, политика конфедециальности у меня готова, осталось при запросе объяснять

https://play.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/about/privacy-security/additional-requirements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прикладываю рыбу, которую надо заполнить:

> ## Who we are
>
> John Doe, author of Blah-blah app, email: johndoe@email.com
>
> ## What data is collected?
>
> The contents of your data is yours and is never collected by us. 
>   Blah-Blah stores this data on a location [...]
>
> Blah-blah does not collect personal identifiable information.  After
>   unexpected errors or crashes of the app, the user may be asked if
>   he/she whants  to send an error report to app developer. Error reports
>   do not contain database contents.  Reports may contain file paths if
>   the error was related to a failed file operation.  Error reports sent
>   from inside the app are sent using [...] error reporting library.
>
> The app AUTHOR does not and never will pass any of this data to third
>   parties.
>
> ### What Android permissions are required?
>
> • Storage: required to allow the user to read/store data 
>    • Contacts: Required to access device
>   contacts to [...]
>   • Fingerprint: Required if you want to use
>   fingerprint unlock.
>   • Camera: Required to take photo and add them to
>   [...]
>   • Wake lock: Some works could take substantial amount of time,
>   so to be efficient app  needs to control device wake lock
>   • Install shortcut: During first start app tries to install shortcut on desktop
>
> ## Special notices
>
> [...]

Comment: Сама политика конфедециальности у меня готова, а вот объясняться при запросе на права у пользователя я не знаю как объяснять, где описать это

Comment: См. раздел *what Android permissions are required* и опиши все там

Comment: То есть здесь ** и запросе на использование данных нужно подробно объяснить** имеется ввиду описать в политике конфедециальности?